# How to display the identity of the server process

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to get the identity of the server process.  It's an MVC 4/Razor project.  This is what I have:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
    <div>
         The identity running this view is @Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
    </div>
```

But I get an error saying the name Thread doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```